# Exposing Service in OpenShift Origin not working

Tags: tomcat, ansible, openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I am new using OpenShift Origin. I've installed 1 master and 2 nodes using ansible-openshift.
Everything appears to be ok. I can access to the dashboard at  http://10.1.10.1:8443. But the problem appears when I want to expose a service so I did:

1. I deployed a tomcat container via Dashboard.
2. Then, I created a route in order to exposed the tomcat through the master, also via Dashboard but when I go to http://10.1.10.1:8080 (master ip:exposed port) does not work, connection refused appears.

OS version

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

OC Version

```
oc v1.4.1+3f9807a
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
Server https://10.1.10.1:8443
openshift v1.4.1+3f9807a
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
```

ansible / hosts

```
# Create an OSEv3 group that contains the masters and nodes groups 
[OSEv3:children] 
masters
nodes
#etcd

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts 
[OSEv3:vars] 
ansible_user=root
ansible_become=true
deployment_type=origin 
openshift_release=1.4.1
containerized=true 
openshift_router_selector='router=true'
openshift_registry_selector='registry=true'
enable_docker_excluder=false 
enable_excluders=false
os_firewall_use_firewalld=false 

# enable htpasswd auth 
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]
openshift_master_htpasswd_users={'admin': '$apr1$zgSjCrLt$1KSuj66CggeWSv.D.BXOA1', 'user': '$apr1$.gw8w9i1$ln9bfTRiD6OwuNTG5LvW50'}

# host group for masters 
[masters]
10.1.10.1 openshift_public_hostname=10.1.10.1 openshift_hostname=os-master

# host group for etcd, should run on a node that is not schedulable
#[etcd]
#54.175.0.44 

# host group for worker nodes, we list master node here so that
# openshift-sdn gets installed. We mark the master node as not 
# schedulable. 
[nodes]
10.1.10.1openshift_hostname=10.1.10.1 openshift_schedulable=false
10.1.10.2openshift_hostname=10.1.10.2openshift_node_labels="{'router':'true','registry':'true'}"
10.1.10.3 openshift_hostname=10.1.10.3 openshift_node_labels="{'router':'true','registry':'true'}"
```

The oc adm diagnostics command shows only 2 warnings:

```
WARN:  [DH0005 from diagnostic MasterConfigCheck@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/host/check_master_config.go:52]
       Validation of master config file '/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml' warned:
       assetConfig.loggingPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view aggregated container logs in the console
       assetConfig.metricsPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view cluster metrics in the console
       auditConfig.auditFilePath: Required value: audit can now be logged to a separate file
WARN:  [DClu0003 from diagnostic NodeDefinition@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/cluster/node_definitions.go:112]
       Node 10.1.10.1 is ready but is marked Unschedulable.
       This is usually set manually for administrative reasons.
       An administrator can mark the node schedulable with:
           oadm manage-node 10.1.10.1 --schedulable=true

       While in this state, pods should not be scheduled to deploy on the node.
       Existing pods will continue to run until completed or evacuated (see
       other options for 'oadm manage-node').
```

Could you please shed some light on this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The web console should show you the correct URL to use to access the expose service. You must use the full hostname OpenShift generates for you, you cannot use an IP address else the router doesn't know how to route the request. Expose routes also use ports 80/443 (HTTP/HTTPS) and not the port your application is using internally. You can also use ``oc get routes`` to see external hostname for your exposed application.

Comment: Hi Graham, 
Thanks for your message. Look my 
oc get routes

tomcat-test-route   10.1.10.1             tomcat-test-deploy   8080-tcp

Comment: You should see a fully qualified domain name not an IP address. What you show doesn't look right. Looks like you have set up the cluster wrongly, or gave an IP address for the hostname when creating the route, when you weren't meant to. Perhaps work through online training examples at https://openshift.katacoda.com/ so you know what to expect. They include creation of routes. Start with course scenario of deploying applications from images.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896356/could-not-access-a-running-docker-image-of-war-with-tomcat-in-minishift-open?noredirect=1#comment72911414_42896356). I have configured ansible-container indeed. May I know which kind of user you have deployed tomcat app? did you use the user 'developer/developer' or did you create another user? 
The possible reason could be insufficient rights for your user (thats true in my experience). I would suggest you two things,

1) Check whether your router/service configured correctly or not by doing [this](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/sdn_troubleshooting.html)

2) If your user doesn't have sufficient roles, then [do this](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-any-docker-image-running-in-your-own-openshift-cluster/) or  [this](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/managing_images.html#allowing-pods-to-reference-images-across-projects) to make pulled image working. ( example:$$$ ***oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default***)